# Run actual main window java Intellij Shortcut

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, program-entry-point, shortcut

How to run actual window main shortcut on Intellij for java?
I have multiples main on my program, but i only want execute actual main when i press:

alt + shift + F10

[When i press alt shift f10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nEbA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift+F10 will run the currently selected run configuration.

[There is no way](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69968) to assign a keyboard shortcut to the specific run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA directly, but you can [try a plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9448-run-configuration-as-action).

Comment: Also solved with: ctrl + shift + f10, thanks.